# Subscribe to a property change event to update the style of a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a `LoggingService` that is mapped to a View. It is displaying some text once modified.

It works fine so far, however would like to modify the color of my text based on the `LoggingType`.

My issue is that I don't find where I should subscribe to the LoggingService property change event to call the below `UpdateTextStyle` method:

```
    private void UpdateTextStyle(ILoggingService logging, string propertyName)
    {
        var loggingType = logging.GetUserLevelLatestLog().Key;
        switch (loggingType)
        {
            case LoggingTypes.Error:
                View.UserInfoLogsTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                View.UserInfoLogsTextBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                break;
        ...
        }
    }
```

Here is the property that is mapped to my View in my VM:

```
    public ILoggingService LoggingService   
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loggingService == null)
            {
                _loggingService = Model.LoggingService;
            }
            return _loggingService;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use on property changed events, unless you know what you are doing in WPF. You will cause a Memory Leak.

I assume you have your `LoggingService` bound to your (I assume) `TextBox` in XAML.

I would therefore suggest that you create a `IValueConverter` for `LoggingTypes` to `Style` then bind your `TextBox.Style` to your `LoggingService.LoggingType` via your converter.

```
<UserControl>
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <LoggingStyleConverter x:Key="LoggingStyleConverter" />
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <TextBox
        Text="{Binding Path=Foo.Bar.LoggingService.Text}"
        Style="{Binding Path=Foo.Bar.LoggingService.Type 
                  Converter={StaticResource LoggingStyleConverter}}"
   />
</UserControl>


public class LoggingStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, blah blah blah)
    {
        var type = (LoggingTypes)value;
        switch (type)
        {
            case blah:
                return SomeStyle;
            default:
                return SomeOtherStyle;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly!
(Had registered to my event in the VM constructor and working but definitely a memory leak and not nice coding either)